# Shell that reads line by line

Tags: c, arrays, shell, scanf, fgets

So I'm making a very basic shell that reads stuff line by line and I'm having issues with the loops.
This is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char* av[ARGVMAX];
  int nArgs, i, j, k;

  fflush(stdout);
  while ( fgets( line, LINESIZE, stdin ) != NULL && line[0] != '\n') {
    for(i = 0; line[i] != '\n'; i++) {
      temp[i] = line[i];
    }
    scanf("%d", &nArgs);
    j = 0;
    while(j<nArgs) {
      temp[i++] = ' ';
      scanf("%c", &temp[i++]);
      j++;
    }
    makeargv(temp, av);
    runcommand(av);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
return 0;
}
```

First of all, what I'm trying to do is turn every singular line that is read into one whole, by other words, reading a "string" and putting it in an array, separating every word with a ' '.

Now my problem is, whenever the program is on "scanf("%c", &temp[i++])" he doesn't let me type anything on the first go, what that means is that whenever I enter the loop for the first time he kind of skips that line of code, but on the other entrances of the loop (second time or third time) he waits for me to write something.

What does this mean? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I read your code correctly, the user types a non-empty line of input, and then has to type a number — which is the number of arguments, N for brevity; and the number must be followed by N single characters, each of which will become an argument?  That doesn't feel like a very pleasant command line interface.  Your code also lacks protections against buffer overflows (what if the user types 999999999 as the number?), etc.  I think you need to think again what you are requiring users to input.  And, as the answer notes, `%c` will read the newline after the number, or the space, or colon, or …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

```
scanf("%d", &nArgs);
```

there remains a `newline` in the input buffer, and this is read by the line

```
scanf("%c", &temp[i++]);
```

Although the format `%d` (and most formats) ignore any leading whitespace in the input buffer, `%c` does not, unless you insert a `space` like this:

```
scanf(" %c", &temp[i++]);
//     ^
```

Comment: What if instead of the function  scanf I was using the function fgets ?
It still does the same think in the fgets function, how do I get it to work ?

Comment: `fgets` always reads the `newline` (if present, for example the last line in a text file might not have a `newline`).